# C# WebClient NTLM authentication starting for each request

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, webclient, ntlm

Consider a simple C# NET Framework 4.0 application, that:

- uses WebClient
- authenticates using NTLM (tested on IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.5 server)
- retrieves a string from an URL multiple times using DownloadString()

Here's a sample that works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL_status = "http://localhost/status";

            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCache.Add(new Uri(URL_status), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));

            WebClient WebClient = new WebClient();
            WebClient.Credentials = myCache;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                string Result = WebClient.DownloadString(new Uri(URL_status));
                Console.WriteLine("Try " + i.ToString() + ": " + Result);
            }

            Console.Write("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

When enabling tracing I see that the NTLM authentication does not persist.

Each time Webclient.DownloadString is called, NTLM authentication starts (server returns "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM" header and the whole authenticate/authorize process repeats; there is no "Connection: close" header).

Wasn't NTLM supposed to authenticate a connection, not a request?

Is there a way to make WebClient reuse an existing connection to avoid having to re-authenticate each request?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After 10 days of trying everything I could think of and learning a lot in the process, I **finally** figured a fix for this issue.

The trick is to enable [`UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing(v=vs.110).aspx) by overriding `GetWebRequest` and setting the property to `true` in the `HttpWebRequest` you get back.

You may want to combine that with the [`ConnectionGroupName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y3d5dts(v=vs.110).aspx) property to avoid the potential use of the connection by unauthenticated applications.

Here is the sample from the question modified to work as expected. It opens a single NTLM authenticated connection and reuses it:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL_status = "http://localhost/status";

            CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
            myCache.Add(new Uri(URL_status), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));

            MyWebClient webClient = new MyWebClient();
            webClient.Credentials = myCache;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                string result = webClient.DownloadString(new Uri(URL_status));
                Console.WriteLine("Try {0}: {1}", i, result);
            }

            Console.Write("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MyWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            if (request is HttpWebRequest) 
            {
                var myWebRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
                myWebRequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
                myWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            }

            return request;
        }
    }   
}
```

At this point I would also like to thank [@Falco Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5273580/falco-alexander) for all the help; while his suggestions didn't quite work for me, he did point me in the right direction to look for and finally find the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check your IIS's setting, though that should be default.

```xml
<windowsAuthentication
   enabled="True"
   authPersistSingleRequest="False"
   UseKernelMode>

</windowsAuthentication>
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347472.aspx

Did you check the zone your localhost IIS is in? This was also a pitfall from the client side in the past when working with WinInet. Check that default behaviour of `WebClient`.

---

Edit:

After reproducing the error, I could figure out it's the missing NTLM **preauthentication** implementation of `WebClient` that keeps you from a single 401 request:

```
var WebClient = new PreAuthWebClient();
WebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass","domain");

//Do your GETs 

Public class PreAuthWebClient: WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest (Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest) base.GetWebRequest (address);
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        return request;
  }
}
```

Comment: The IIS settings are default; I just tried manually disabling authPersistSingleRequest and no change - each request I make using WebClient is still authenticated separately. Same thing happens if it's connecting to IIS on the same machine or on a different machine. Authentication is successful and it works, but each request is authenticated instead of just the first one.

Comment: P.s.: if I try to reach the same URL for example with Firefox it works as expected: the first request gets 401, then after authentication/authorization exchanges all subsequent requests are 200/304 responses, so it shouldn't be a server configuration issue.

Comment: If you inspect your fireFox session, is there an auth cookie persisting after the first request? this would lead to the fact that default WebClient is not cookie aware. check for WebRequest or google for "Cookie aware WebClient"

Comment: No cookies are being set by the server (neither in Firefox nor when examining headers in app trace).

Comment: Headers sent by the server after successful authentication (along with a 200 response code): `Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2016 11:04:00 GMT
Etag: "126c7343821ad21:0"
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Sep 2016 18:49:52 GMT
Persistent-Auth: true
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET`

Comment: strange: I checked your code here with an IIS on a different machine and it behaves like expected: 2x 401 (1st with empty auth header, 2nd NTLM Negotiation) Type and 5x 200 (1st with full auth header, 2-5th no header, so I guess through Kerberos)

Comment: Fiddler acting as a proxy was hiding the problem in my case. After going directly, I could see & solve the problem. see my addition to the answer

Comment: I'm afraid using PreAuthenticate did not change anything on my machine (p.s. "Public" needs to be all lowercase "public"). I appreciate your help though and if nothing works I will accept this answer for being the closest one. If it lights any bulbs, I noticed the first (401) and third (200) responses return `Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5` header while the second (401) one returns `Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`.

Comment: can you both try to request an IIS different than you localhost one and check proxy behaviour like fiddler inspection?

Comment: That's the thing - Fiddler shows as expected (2 x 401 then 200), but in the trace it is obvious the NTLM authorization happens for each request. I tried also with WebRequest, but same thing. Maybe there is a better way in C# to manually handle requests and connections?

Comment: I'd recommend first to find out why you get this  `Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0` responses....this is weird

Comment: This happens only on my test (local PC) IIS, doesn't happen on the intranet server. So, when you test the above code and verify trace logs, you do NOT get authentication for each request?

Comment: correct, with overridden preauthentication there is only a single NTLM auth header and 401. I guess your local IIS interferes with some other web service installed. try to check with `netstat -a -b`or similar

Comment: netstat shows that a new TCP connection is opened for each request. Could you please let me know what .target framework version are you compiling for, maybe that's an issue (I am limited to 4.0 for this project)?

Comment: I meant netstat to use with the -a option to see what else is listening to http requests because this is my guess to be the culprit.  I can restest tomorrow with 4.0 when I am in the office

Comment: OK, I have setup a clean IIS 8.5 install on AWS and am testing now there. Here is what I have found so far: 1. changing target version doesn't help
2. netstats doesn't show any other connections to the server
3. in my code, 5 connections are opened and closed after idle time
4. when I use PreAuthenticate, 6 connections are opened (1 for preauth then 5 for WebClient?)
5. if I move authentication from WebClient to PreAuthWebClient request, I get 5 connections again
Conclusion: At this point I am out of ideas... I might as well set "Connection: close" to at least avoid idle connections.

Comment: Update: strange thing, I just noticed that if I have Fiddler open, the code works fine (only 1 connection). If I close Fiddler, I am back to 5 connections. So it's not a code issue, but something on the local PC. No idea what though, will update if I figure it out.

Comment: I do not share your conclusion as this behaviour was exaclty as on my machine (see my comment Sep 30 at 12:36 +13:26). With fiddler acting as proxy it did not matter, if I sent my requests with preauth or not. which is not so unusual, because it created completly new requests. Are you sure you implemented overriding the request correctly?

Comment: I finally figured this out, see my answer for the solution. @Falco Alexander thank you for all your help and pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

`NtlmAuthenticator` is deprecated for Nuget version 110+. But you can use `NetworkCredential` as follows.

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://example.com");
        
options.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
{
    Domain = "corp",
    UserName = "userName",
    Password = "password"
};

var client = new RestClient(options);
```