# Webclient return 500 error when try to connect same server that it published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, webclient

I have a controller with 2 methods

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] TaskRequest value)
{
  var content = CustomerRepository.GetUserInfo(value.Id);
  if (content != null)
  {
    return Ok(content);
  }
  else
  {
    return BadRequest();
  }
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Status()
{
  return Ok("work");
}
```

Method `Status` i used to check work of service.

So, when i run my service on my device everything  work fine. But when i post on IIS, method Create (that use WebClient) return 500 error. IIS server located on same ip that WebClient try to make request. Lets this ip will be `10.10.10.10`.

In method Create i in `CustomerRepository.GetUserInfo(value.Id)` use `WebClient`

```
try
{
  byte[] response = client.UploadData(requestEndpoint, "POST",
      System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData));
  client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
  string responce = client.Encoding.GetString(response);

  return responce;  
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  throw e;
}
```

`requestData` generate before this part of code and contain xml.

`requestEndpoint = "http://10.10.10.10:80/Sevice/Service.svc"`

I test everything parts of code and exactly sure that problem in WebClient when it try to make request in IIS on same ip address that IIS located. How can i fix this problem?

UPD
Add ISS log information

```
2020-07-07 08:52:06 10.10.10.10 POST /api/task/create - 80 - 11.11.11.11 PostmanRuntime/7.26.1 - 307 0 0 15
2020-07-07 08:52:06 10.10.10.10 POST /Service/Service.svc - 80 - 10.10.10.10 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-US) - 401 0 0 0
2020-07-07 08:52:06 10.10.10.10 POST /api/task/create - 443 - 11.11.11.11 PostmanRuntime/7.26.1 http://10.10.10.10/api/task/create 500 0 0 15
```

Change server ip to `10.10.10.10` and my ip to `11.11.11.11`

Comment: Is there a sub-status code with the 500? It could reveal more information: [The HTTP status code in IIS 7 and later versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0).

Comment: This is one of the problems that prevented me from understanding the cause of the error.
I used Postman to make request and when i post to create method it just return me `500 Internal Server Error` without any description

Comment: 1) Can you look in the Windows Event Logs on the server? 2) Does a simple "hello world" HTML page work?

Comment: 1) Yes, i got access. Added to the question
2) Yes.

Comment: That 401 (ie. Unauthorized) could be a clue: [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). Does it work better if you start from https:// instead of http:// ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling 500.0 is caused by unhandled exceptions in your code base, so you need to handle them properly. The 401.0 error seems to be irrelevant at this moment.

Comment: Thx everyone. I added in `startap.cs` work with https and everything work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i answer for my own question case need to close it.

Thx [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton) or suggesting checking the logs and exploring query statuses. In my case i got redirect in 1-st query. And in 2-nd query i got unauthorized. So i start to check how fix it. Here is my way to fix:

1. I go to IIS and check firewall rules. Check that inbound and outbound rules got port that you used;
2. In IIS add ip address, where located IIS, to trusted sites;
3. In my project in `startap.cs` added to work with Https:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseHsts(); //this place 
  }

  ...

}
```

After all these points, my problem has been fixed.

I also advise you to read the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1) shared by [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li).

P.S. My Technical Lead also advised watching this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787404/c-sharp-webclient-ntlm-authentication-starting-for-each-request) if my method doesn’t work.